# Powershell: Create Az copy to the blob Container log file or verbose

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Hello I am new to powershell, I have a powershell script below that copy c:files root/folder/files

```
$StorageAccountKey=" "
$sourceFileRootDirectory=" "
$StorageAccountName=" "
$ContainerName=" "
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey 
$StorageAccountKey
$container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $ctx

if ($container) {
    $filesToUpload = Get-ChildItem $sourceFileRootDirectory -Recurse -File

    foreach ($x in $filesToUpload) {
        $blobName = ($x.fullname.Substring($x.PSDrive.Root.Length)).Replace("\", "/")

 Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $x.fullname -Container $container.Name -Blob $blobName - 
 Context $ctx -Force:$Force 
    }
}
```

The issue that I am currently having is when I run the script inside my storage blob grabs the full path which creates

\Users\Glen\Desktop\democontainer\ (then whatever is inside)

How can I be able to trim so that it grabs the root folder excluding
\Users\Glen\Desktop for any users that runs and just grabs the root folder "democontainer"

As for the end result I would like an out-file with date-time that gives information about folder structure

I have code:

```
Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Glen\Desktop\democontainer\demolog.txt"
```

However I'm not sure where to add inside my currentcode and to format the day it was copied to storage blob

Comment: Hi Glen, for us to be able to help you with your question, you first need to help us understand you question by providing more detail. Please edit your question to help us help you! As it is right now there doesn't seem to be a question but just a description of your code. Please provide a specific issue, problem, error, or anything else that is necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you I tried to add in more details about the issue i am having with and some information i have researched on. Hopefully these explains it

Comment: "*I would like to grab the root folder only "democontainer" (then whatver is inside)*" I don't exactly understand thisalso the usage for `Out-File` is:

`Command thats output you are trying to pipe | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Users\Glen\Desktop\democontainer\demolog.txt" -Append`

Comment: When all is copied, I would like an Out-File of storage blob structure

Comment: Try using `Get-Item ".\$sourceRootFileDirectory"` and if you only want the name and not the item information use `Get-Item ".\$sourceRootFileDirectory"|% Name`

Comment: I think I got my issue solve

$sourceFileRootDirectory="C:\Users\Glen\Desktop\democontainer"
$sourceparent = Split-Path -Parent -Path $sourceFileRootDirectory

 foreach ($x in $filesToUpload) {
            $blobName = ($x.fullname.Substring($sourceparent.Length)).Replace("\", "/").trim('/')   
            Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $x.fullname -Container $container.Name -Blob $blobName -Context $ctx -Force:$Force 
            Out-File -Append -FilePath ./file.txt -InputObject $x.FullName 
        } 


@nico nekoru thank you for the help and taking some time

Comment: @GlenSale Since your issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer?

Comment: @jim xu i have re posted my solution using

$sourceparent = Split-Path -Parent -Path $sourceFileRootDirectory

and inside my foreach

 $blobName = ($x.fullname.Substring($sourceparent.Length)).Replace("\", "/").trim('/')

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue with  output only the root directory with these code I found

```
$StorageAccountKey=" "
$sourceFileRootDirectory=" "
$sourceparent = Split-Path -Parent -Path $sourceFileRootDirectory
$StorageAccountName=" "
$ContainerName=" "
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $ctx

 if ($container) {
        $filesToUpload = Get-ChildItem $sourceFileRootDirectory -Recurse -file 



        foreach ($x in $filesToUpload) {
            $blobName = ($x.fullname.Substring($sourceparent.Length)).Replace("\", "/").trim('/')   
            Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $x.fullname -Container $container.Name -Blob $blobName -Context $ctx -Force:$Force 
         
        } 

         
             
}
```